# Synchronous calls using RemoteObject

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

Is there a way to make synchronous calls using RemoteObject in Flex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved the same in two ways: First, as said above the use of state machines. It may get tricky at times. Second, the use of command queues - I think this is the best way to do it... but the downside is that the UI may not be very reflective in this time.

Comment: Can make the UI more friendly to the user by displaying a loading indicator and informative status messages.  With Flex this is really easy to do - just bind something in your loading component to the value of a loadingText:String property in your model or presentation model, and just update the loadingText value from your Controller as it executes the consecutive commands or service calls in your queue.  Presto!

Answer (score 5):

All IO in Flex is asynchronous. The typical pattern to deal with this is to use an [`AsyncResponder`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/rpc/AsyncResponder.html).  For instance:

```
var t:AsyncToken = remoteObject.methodCall();
t.addResponder(new AsyncResponder(resultEvent, faultEvent));
```

Comment: An AsyncResponder is used for asynchronous call responses - it can't let you do this in synchronous way :(

Comment: There is no (clean) way to make IO synchronous in Flex.

Comment: and @Sandy If I have a Model (on the Flex side) rendered in an editable DataGrid cell and I want to validate it's input (per a some format) then send that to the server and validate (say, uniqueness).  How can I then invalidate the first Validator in a a chained fashion?  

My current implementation uses a DataGrid's itemEditEnd to validate input on a cell and afterward makes a call to the Server via a RemoteObject.  Depending on what I get back though, I need to invalidate that cell that was just edited.  Any thoughts?  _Thanks so much!_

Comment: Hi Brian.  I'm not sure what the best way to do that is.  Perhaps you should ask this as another top level question?

Answer (score 2):

think twice when u want it to be synchronous.

Do u know what synchronous mean? it will FREEZE your application until it receive data. Unless u are pretty sure that your remote calling can receive return value immediately (super fast network connection).

if your function call depends on each other, i would suggest you implement a state machine. e.g.

after 1st async call, your state becomes STATE_1, and your next function call will check on this state variable, to decide next move (ignore the current call or carry on).

my 2 cents.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We are on a local company network, but still implemented this using the state machine.

Thanks, anyways!

Answer (score 1):

If you want synchronous behavior, just add a wait after you make the call.

EDIT: I've added code for the chaining behavior I was talking about. Just replace the result handler each subsequent time you call the remoteObject.

```
...
remoteObject.function1(...);
...

private var resultHandler1(event:ResultEvent):void
{
    ...
    remoteObject.removeEventListener(resultHandler1);
    remoteObject.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, resultHandler2);
    remoteObject.function2(...);
}

private var resultHandler2(event:ResultEvent):void
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Crap! You can't wait in flex and second, you don't know the timing in which the call would complete.

Comment: Well, I meant wait as in, do nothing. And of course you don't know the timing, that's why the call is asynchronous. But you can just call the remoteObject again from the resultHandler of one call and chain them in that fashion.

Comment: This seems like the proper approach, if one is dependent on the other, merely use the built-in event hierarchy to delegate things on time.  Since the second remote objects call happens on the completion of the first, we know that basing the second off of the first is available and accurate.

Answer (score 0):

No, why would you wish to do that anyway.
Flex makes things asynchronous so that the user isn't forced to sit and wait while data is coming back.
It would be a very poor user expereince if each time an app requested data the user had to wait on it coming back before anything else could happen.

---

from comment

No you don't need synchronus behaivour. If you're making say 2 calls and call 2 comes in before call 1, but 2 relies on the data inside 1 then you're left with either don't fire off event 2 till 1 comes back (this will slow down your app - much like synchronus events) or implement a way to check that event 1 has come back in event 2's handler (there are many ways you could do this).
If you're firing off many events then why not have a wrapper class of some description that tracks your events and doesn't do anything on the responses until all events are back.
You can use the AsyncToken to keep track of individual requests, so if you are firing of loads at once then you can find out exaclty whats come back and whats not.

Comment: Huh - when you need to make multiple remote object calls where the result of one depends on another, you need synchronous behaviour. Adding a facade is not always possible - specifically when server code is not in your hands.

Comment: There are situations when you need exactly this - user needs to sit and wait till the application load all necessary data from the server

Answer (score 0):

you should perhaps try and make one request with with all the data u want to be recieved synchronous and then make the different classes that need data listen to the correct data for that class.

ex:

```
  // request
  remoteobject.GetData(); 

  // on received request
  private function receivedData(evt:ResultEvent):void   
  {

     for each (var resultobject:ResultObjectVO in evt.result)
     {

        var eventModel:Object;

        var event:DataEvents = new DataEvents(resultobject.ResultType);
        event.data          = eventModel;

        eventdispatcher.dispatchEvent(event);
     }
  }
```

Something like this. Hopes this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you call a synchronous `XMLHttpRequest` calling JavaScript on Flex, you can do this.

Answer (score 0):

You all are somehow mistaken or not using flex from adobe, if you send 2 calls to the server, no matter if each has an individual resquestObject the second one will ONLY be returned after the first one finish, even if the second one takes 1 milisecond to process. Just try the fibonnaci 1/40 example.

Comment: This will only happen in case your calls are to the same domain - Flex follows the HTTP standards and uses the OS networking stack. Most of the operating systems will open only 2 connections per server. In case you have different 2 servers, you will have 2 connections per server, in all 4 connections. And am sure on this :)